# Show the progress bar while uploading video with Angular

Tags: angular, minio

I am uploading large files to MinIO with Angular2. I want to show the progress bar while user is uploading the video.

Work flow is that I first post a data to the API, which gives me link where I can upload video directly to Minio (in response).

I tried various options and nothing works, I allways get the response during subscribe 'null'..

Service code for first POST request, where I get direct link for uploading to MinIO:

```
  postLecture(lectureData: any): Observable<any> {
    this.addJwtToHeaders();
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/x_lecture/`;
    return this.http.post<any>(url, lectureData, httpOptions);
  }
```

Request which send data to MinIO and from which I want the progress bar:

```
      uploadVideoToMinio(
        url: string,
        lectureData: any,
        file: any
      ): Observable<any> {
        this.addJwtToHeaders();
        let value = lectureData.videos[0].video_format;
        let video = new FormData();
        video.append('video', file);
    
        let httpOptions2 = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mp4',
          }),
          reportProgress: true,
          options: {
            observe: 'events',
          },
        };
    
        return this.http.put<any>(url, file, httpOptions2);
      }
```

My component.ts code is:

```
    this.uploadSubs = this.uploadVideoService
      .postLecture(lectureData)
      .subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.type);
          console.log(res.type.DownloadProgress);
          if (res.videos[0].video_put_url) {
            let url: string = res.videos[0].video_put_url;
            this.minioSubs = this.uploadVideoService
              .uploadVideoToMinio(url, lectureData, this.selectedVideo)
              .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                  console.log(res);

                  if (res.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                    console.log(Math.round((100 / res.total) * res.loaded));
                  }
                  console.log(res);
                  console.log(res.type);
                  console.log(res.type.DownloadProgress);
                },
                (error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                }
              );
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also tried different httpOptions, like:

```
let httpOptions2 = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mp4',
  }),
  reportProgress: true,
};
```

Comment: along with `reportProgress`, try adding this option too: `observe: 'events'`

Comment: I tried, like that: let httpOptions2 = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mp4',
          }),
          reportProgress: true,
          options: {
            observe: 'events',
          },
        };

Comment: What is the reason you put the "options" in front of "observe"? you can check the method signature here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b358b61304b4c7b455f68436787ceec062c6c2f2/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L2292

Comment: I am getting strange strange error. Can you check it please? https://imgur.com/a/3fmupSJ

Comment: you could either pass the option object {} directly, or as you currently declare as httpOptions2 = {} but now put `as const` after that => `httpOpts = {} as const`

Comment: Thank you! It works now. You can answer my question and I will accept it. Can you please also describe me, whay is that needed? That I needed to put as const after my httpOptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summary:

- You need to pass the `observe` option to fulfill the http.post signature, by default, the value of `observe` is `body`
- `as const` is `Typescript` thing, not angular, scroll down to `OBSERVE AND RESPONSE TYPES` in the [following section](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response) to understand more.

I also suggest you take a tour on the [link above](https://angular.io/guide/http#communicating-with-backend-services-using-http) to fully understand the http service, it will benefit you later.

Comment: Thank you. If you think that my question could help someone please upvote it.